# MySql table performance optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE rel_score (
  user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  score_date date NOT NULL,
  rel_score decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  doc_count int(8) NOT NULL
  total_doc_count int(8) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id,score_date),
  KEY SCORE_DT_IDX (score_date)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=1
```

The table will store rel_score value for every user in the application for every day since 1st Jan 2000 till date. I estimated the total number records will be over 700 million. I populated the table with 6 months data (~ 30 million rows) and the query response time is about 8 minutes. Here is my query,

```
select 
  user_id, max(rel_score) as max_rel_score
from
  rel_score
where score_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-06-30'
group by user_id
order by max_rel_score desc;
```

I tried optimizing the query using the following techniques,

1. Partitioning on the score_date column
2. Adding an index on the score_date column

The query response time improved marginally to a little less than 8 mins.

How can I improve response time? Is the design of the table appropropriate?

Also, I cannot move the old data to archive as an user is allowed to query on the entire data range.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan. I think an index on `score_date` might actually slow the query down, as it will make the optimiser go for an index seek and lookup operation, where a table scan would be more efficient? Finally, I am not against MySQL, but if you have an application with 150k users, have been established for 13 years and are offering the ability to query all of those 13 years, then it is possibly time to consider upgrading from an opensource DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

If you partition your table on the same level of the score_date you will not reduce the query response time.

Try to create another attribut that will contain only the year of the date, cast it to an INTEGER , partition your table on this attribut (you will get 13 partition), and reexecute your query to see .

Answer (score 0):

Your primary index should do a good job of covering the table.  If you didn't have it, I would suggest building an index on `rel_score(user_id, score_date, rel_score)`.  For your query, this is a "covering" index, meaning that the index has all the columns in the query, so the engine never has to access the data pages (only the index).

The following version might also make good use of this index (although I much prefer your version of the query):

```
select u.user_id,
       (select max(rel_score)
        from rel_score r2
        where r2.user_id = r.user_id and 
              r2.score_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-06-30'
      ) as rel_score
from (select distinct user_id
      from rel_score
      where score_date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-06-30'
     ) u
order by rel_score desc;
```

The idea behind this query is to replace the aggregation with a simple index lookup.  Aggregation in MySQL is a slow operation -- it works much better in other databases so such tricks shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Surely since the clustered index is on `(user_id, score_date)`, an index on `(user_id, score_date, rel_score)` will essentially just duplicate the table (but leaving out 2 columns). I also think that MySQL would still chose the Clustered index scan even if this index exists (it does in [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64621/3) anyway)